# How to avoid git submodule commit id being committed?

Tags: git, version-control

I have a git repository A containing two submodule B and C. This repo has been downloaded on three different machines M1, M2 and M3.

Now i need submodule B and C to remain on an older commit on different machines. I need them to be at the latest commit on M1, B on an older and C on the latest on M2, and B on the latest and C on an older on M2. (Don'ask why, please...)

If i do a commit and push on M1, the commit memorize the commit id for repo A, AND submodule B and C, and this is fine.

If i do a commit on M2, the commit does the same, but this is not good for B is set on a older commit. The same goes on M3 for C.

It is possible to commit on M3 and M2 without memorizing the commit id of the repo that is set on an older commit? (the content of B and C are yet gitignored)

The problem is that i need to commit from all the three machines to pass changes made to repo A (and from M2 and M3 to commit changes on either B or C), but if i commit from M3, for example, it takes with it the commit id of the submodule C with the older commit and the result is that, when i pull to M1 submodule C get stucked on the older commit from M3 and doing a pull stops to the older commit instead of the latest.

NOTE: Until now, the only solution I found was git add to a commit from M3 any file i changed singularly, so to exclude the submodules from commit, but it is not exactly convenient...